# Nuxtjs project , this.$route.meta can not print meta

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

well I write a meta infomation in a vue page, when I use "this.$route.meta",it can not print anything about meta infomation. But when I open this vue page element, there is a meta infomation,I can not print it.What can I do

```
export default {
 watch: {
  $route() {
    console.log(this.$route.meta)
    }
   }
 }

export default {
  components: {
    Teacontent
  },
  head() {
    return {
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', title: 'Tea Manage' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll be easier if you directly copy paste the code within your question, it'll help people to retry themself as a picture is not copy pastable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were searching for your meta information in the wrong place. The meta info of your nuxt page cannot be found on the `$route` property (although this property has a different kind of meta itself).

What you are looking for is not `this.$route.meta`, but rather `this.$metaInfo.meta`:

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$metaInfo.meta)
  },
  head() {
    return {
      meta: [{ hid: 'description', name: 'description', title: 'Tea Manage' }]
    }
  }
}
```